# Copy multiple textarea with 1 button

Tags: copy, clipboard

I want copy 5 textarea (text) in html with 1 button press.

```
<textarea id="target">1</textarea>

<textarea id="target">2</textarea>

<textarea id="target">3</textarea>

<textarea id="target">4</textarea>

<textarea id="target">5</textarea>
```

I want press button and copy **12345** to clip board.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with same **id** but you can do this with same **class**.

```
 <textarea class="target">1</textarea>

<textarea class="target">2</textarea>

<textarea class="target">3</textarea>

<textarea class="target">4</textarea>

<textarea class="target">5</textarea>

<button id="btn">Copy</button>
```

Now use JQuery to get values

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){
var value='';
 $('.target').each(function(){
  value+=$(this).val();
});
 alert(value);
});
});
```

Comment: I can't use, pls give me a example at jsfiddle

Comment: You will need an extra <textarea> or input field to select result. so that's why I added new <textarea> with id #res. This is because select() only works with <textarea> and <input> elements. Sorry for late response. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Welcome. Sorry I didn't see clipboard at first .